# Can't access NSObject class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, class

I have a class called XMLParser and I want to be able to access the methods inside this class from ViewController class, but for some reason it won't allow me to do so.
Any help on how to load this in viewDidLoad??

***XMLParser.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface XMLParser : NSObject

{
    bool isStatus;
    XMLParser *currentProfile;
    XMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray *profile;
    NSString *firstName;
}

- (void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;
- (void)loadXML;

@end
```

***XMLParser.m***

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

-(void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    profile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [XMLParser alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
        [profile addObject:currentProfile];
    }
}

-(void)loadXML
{
    [self loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
}

@end
```

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    XMLParser = [[XMLParser alloc]init]; //======This doesn't seem to work?
    [XMLParser loadXML];//=======================This doesn't seem to work?
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**CODE FOR DISPLAYING THE PARSED DATA IN A LABEL**

```
- (IBAction)showProfilesButton:(id)sender
{
    XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
    [parser loadXML];


    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(XMLParser *obj in self.profile)
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->firstName];
    }

    CGSize expectedSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(520, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, expectedSize.width, expectedSize.height);
    [profilesLabel setFrame:newFrame];
    [profilesLabel setText:str];

}
```

Comment: You need to declare a variable (or a property) of type `XMLParser *`. What you have in your code is a syntax error.

Comment: You should have added that as an answer.

Comment: Define "it won't allow me to do so".  Until you do that you've not met the minimum standard for asking a question here.

Comment: @HotLicks What I meant was, I was getting errors with this code: XMLParser = [[XMLParser alloc]init]; [XMLParser loadXML]; but it's fixed now ;)

Comment: But you never copied/pasted the exact messages, or even paraphrased them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
XMLParser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
```

is not assigning a variable and is syntactically incorrect. You likely want something more like

```
XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
```

This properly assigns the allocated and initialized instance to the local variable "parser".

To use it afterwards, you would call

```
[parser loadXML];
```

Comment: Great! Glad to be of assistance. If you would like more information on Objective-C to expand your understanding and make debugging a whole lot easier, check out http://docs.happycoders.org/orgadoc/dev/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf. Also, please remember to accept my answer using the checkmark below the number on the left. This marks the question as answered so others won't be apt to trying answering.

Comment: Thanks Grimless! I have another issue with displaying the parsed data in a label. The parsed data shows up correctly in command output window but for some reason I can't get it to show on a label. See the code added above, its a button that should display the data in a profilesLabel.

Comment: In Objective-C, direct access to members using -> is generally considered to be a very naughty practice. In this case, trying to access `firstName` directly from an external scope should raise an error at compile time. Instead, you will want to expose the `firstName` data through a method on `XMLParser`. Below the `-(void)loadXML;` line in the header, add `- (NSString*) firstName;`. In the implementation (.m) add `- (NSString*) firstName { return firstName; }`. This creates what's called a "getter" that properly protects the data inside of the XMLParser instance.

Comment: Thanks again! I did that but still I get errors. in for(XMLParser *obj in self.profile) it says property 'profile' not found of type "ViewController" and in [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->firstName]; it says instance variable 'firstName' is protected

Comment: OK, at this point, I really have to recommend that you read through the Objective-C PDF I linked. It will answer your questions far better than I can in this limited format. If you find you still have issues once you have read through that, feel free to open a new question and I will take another crack at it.

Comment: I read through the PDF file you sent and I still can't seem to figure out how to fix my problem...I have posted a new question, it would be great if you could help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849144/how-to-display-xml-parsed-data-in-a-label-ios