# How to display XML parsed data in a label iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uilabel

I have 2 classes: `XMLParser` and `ViewController`. All the code for the parsing process is in the `XMLParser`. I call the date being parsed in `ViewController` and display it in Command Output window using `NSLog`. Now my problem is I can't seem to get the data to be displayed in a `UILabel` called "profilesLabel". In the `ViewController` is a `UIButton` called "showProfilesButton" which should display the data in profilesLabels text. See the attempted code in ViewController.m.

Any help would be appreciated!

***XMLParser.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface XMLParser : NSObject

{
    bool isStatus;
    XMLParser *currentProfile;
    XMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray *profile;
    NSString *firstName;
}

- (void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;
- (void)loadXML;

@end
```

***XMLParser.m***

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

-(void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    profile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [XMLParser alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
        NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
        [profile addObject:currentProfile];
    }
}

-(void)loadXML
{
    [self loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
}

@end
```

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profilesLabel;

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize profilesLabel;



//Code for the button to display the profiles
- (IBAction)showProfilesButton:(id)sender
{
    XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
    [parser loadXML];


    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(XMLParser *obj in self.profile)
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", obj->firstName];
        profilesLabel.text = str;
    }

    CGSize expectedSize = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(520, 1000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, expectedSize.width, expectedSize.height);
    [profilesLabel setFrame:newFrame];
    [profilesLabel setText:str];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: You declared `profile` in `XMLParser` class. Can you access that by `self.profile` from `viewController` class?

Comment: I think its li'l bit wrong approach.Based on the url and amount of data returned XMLParser may take time to parse the data.

Better if you use 

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser; 

for identifying correct time and data to display in label.

Comment: @cjd Thanks for your answer. Can you explain a bit more, or maybe show in edit how you would do it? Thanks

Comment: @Anusha Sorry I am new to Objective-C, how can I acces profile from XMLParser then? Thanks

Comment: @azi_santos in your class containing parser,implement one delegate which method will be called on  - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser; to indicate end of parsing in your ViewController. Write your whole code starting from  NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; in that method.